# How to assign array of a particular index to another nested array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, angular8

I am adding a material expansion panel on click of a button and trying to bind the values of the content into each index of the model array. My array has another array defined in it which gives me a headache when assigning the value of the nested array. The 1st index binds properly but the 2nd and 3rd index of the array repeats. I am also doing 2 way binding, which I will remove and bind it to the service.

The 1st index binds properly but the 2nd and 3rd index of the array repeats. I am also doing 2 way binding, which I will remove and bind it to the service.

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-content>
  <div class="pesticide-info">
    <h2 class="h3 text-center">Pesticide Information</h2>
    <mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of recordPesticideInfos; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            Pesticide Product
          </mat-panel-title>
          <mat-panel-description>
            Enter the Pesticide Information
          </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div *ngFor="let pest of item.pesticideInfo; let j = index" [attr.data-index]="j">
          <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="auto">
            <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
            <!-- <input name=Product{{index}} [(ngModel)]="recordPesticideInfos[index].pesticideInfo[index].Product" placeholder="item">-->
            <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" [(ngModel)]="pest.Product" name=Product{{countOfProduct}}
              #Product="ngModel">                
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
      <div class="add-product text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-success text-white" (click)="addItem()" style="text-align: center"><i
            class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</a>
      </div>
    </mat-accordion>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

```
export class RecordPesticideInfo {
RecordPesticideInfosId: number;
    RecordId: number;
    PesticideInfoId: number;
    CountOfPestcideProduct: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    pesticideInfo: PesticideInfo[];
```

}

```
addItem() {   
// push object that you need to be added into array
this.recordPesticideInfos.push({
  RecordPesticideInfosId: null, RecordId: null,
  PesticideInfoId: null, CountOfPestcideProduct: this.countOfProduct++,
  title: "Pesticide Product", description: "Enter the Pesticide Information",
  pesticideInfo: this.pesticides as PesticideInfo[]
  // pesticideInfo: Object.keys(this.pesticides).map(i => this.pesticides[this.countOfProduct++])
});
```

}

I want to bind a new value of array on each button click
Here is the stackblitz url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylqkum

Comment: can you create a stackblitz from this?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylqkum

Comment: I think that you can use the spread operator to get a copy, some like `pesticideInfo: [{...this.pesticides[0]}]` but I'm not sure about your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
pesticideInfo: this.pesticides as PesticideInfo[]
```

Every time you added a new product it got the exact same object reference from your this.pesticide member variable.

The reason why it worked for the first item is that there you created the new object inline:

```
pesticideInfo: [{
    PesticideInfoId: null,
    Product: null      
}]
```

I added this new function for new default product item creation:

```
  private createNewPesticide() {
    return {
      PesticideInfoId: null, 
      Product: null
    }
  }
```

Check the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfk38x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thank You Robert ! This works now. I was so involved in handling the index that I overlooked this. TY !